# Android Custom Package Options for ABI split

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, 64-bit, abi

Is there a way to give custom package options for a ABI split ?

I tried doing

```
splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "armeabi-v7a","arm64-v8a","x86","x86_64"
            universalApk true {
                packagingOptions {
                    // exclude 64 bit libs for universalAPK
                    exclude 'lib/x86_64/**'
                    exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/**'
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

but it gave me an error

> No signature of method: java.lang.Boolean.call() is applicable for
>   argument types:
>   (app_7ivhksmndk7z0svs7y33ri7hq$_run_closure1$_closure12$_closure46$_closure47)
>   values:
>   [app_7ivhksmndk7z0svs7y33ri7hq$_run_closure1$_closure12$_closure46$_closure47@6bbef142]
>   Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long),
>   each(groovy.lang.Closure), and(java.lang.Boolean),
>   any(groovy.lang.Closure)